# Redis HA with Sentinel on Docker

Tags: docker, redis, high-availability, sentinel, redis-sentinel

I'm struggling now for a week with the Redis HA on Docker. I am not quite convinced if my intentions will even works. The documentation is understandable, but there are many examples which do not correspond to the documentation.

Well, what I want to do is set up a Redis Cluster with 1 master, 2 replicas and 3 Sentinel. This is hosted on a 192.168.1.10. I want to acess the Cluster via an App coming from 192.168.1.11.
The RedisCluster is working properly without the Sentinel. Replication works fine.

When I start the sentinel, I get the following log entries on all 3 Redis-Container: redis-0, redis-1 and redis-2

```
1:S 22 Dec 2020 18:43:38.349 * Connecting to MASTER 172.20.0.2:6379
1:S 22 Dec 2020 18:43:38.350 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 22 Dec 2020 18:43:38.350 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 22 Dec 2020 18:43:38.350 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 22 Dec 2020 18:43:38.350 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request eac3aa540e767589e9673ae0ed844d985ed2abb2:1856).
1:S 22 Dec 2020 18:43:38.350 * Master is currently unable to PSYNC but should be in the future: -NOMASTERLINK Can't SYNC while not connected with my master
```

I tried to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEg7s3i6Jak) tutorial but it didn't work. Same behavier as described.
These are my Docker commands

```
# Redis (with custom redis.conf will not work the replication) so i keep it simple this way.
docker run --name redis-0 -d --network redis -p 6379:6379 redis redis-server
docker run --name redis-1 -d --network redis -p 6380:6379 redis redis-server --slaveof redis-0 6379
docker run --name redis-2 -d --network redis -p 6381:6379 redis redis-server --slaveof redis-0 6379
# Sentinel
docker run -d --name sentinel-0 --network redis -v ${PWD}/sentinel-0:/etc/redis/  redis  redis-sentinel /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
docker run -d --name sentinel-1 --network redis -v ${PWD}/sentinel-1:/etc/redis/  redis  redis-sentinel /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
docker run -d --name sentinel-2 --network redis -v ${PWD}/sentinel-2:/etc/redis/  redis  redis-sentinel /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
```

These is the `sentinel.conf`

```
port 5000
# sentinel monitor <master-group-name> <ip> <port> <quorum>
sentinel monitor mymaster 172.20.0.2 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 1000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1
```

The Sentinel-Container have write access to the `sentinel.conf`.

Those are my `iptables` instructions

```
# Redis
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.0.2:6379
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6380 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.0.3:6379
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6381 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.0.4:6379

# Sentinel
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 26379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.0.5:6379
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 26380 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.0.6:6379
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 26381 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.20.0.7:6379
```

I'm well aware of the Documentation:

> Since Sentinels auto detect replicas using masters INFO output
> information, the detected replicas will not be reachable, and Sentinel
> will never be able to failover the master, since there are no good
> replicas from the point of view of the system, so there is currently
> no way to monitor with Sentinel a set of master and replica instances
> deployed with Docker, unless you instruct Docker to map the port 1:1.
>
> For the first problem, in case you want to run a set of Sentinel
> instances using Docker with forwarded ports (or any other NAT setup
> where ports are remapped), you can use the following two Sentinel
> configuration directives in order to force Sentinel to announce a
> specific set of IP and port:
>
> sentinel announce-ip 
> sentinel announce-port 
> Note that Docker has the ability to run in host networking mode (check the
> `--net=host` option for more information). This should create no issues since ports are not remapped in this setup.

I just dont know where to place the announce-IP and Port and what the Value of those has to be. Also notice that the `--net=host` will not work, because i have 3 container each on the same Host:port.

How can I run Sentinel in a Docker environment which serves me for the Redis HA?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

I did a Failover test and have following result (same result on Sentinel 0, 1 and 2)

```
# docker exec -it sentinel-0 redis-cli -p 5000
127.0.0.1:5000> SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster
1) "172.20.0.2"
2) "6379"
# docker stop redis-0
redis-0
# docker exec -it sentinel-0 redis-cli -p 5000
127.0.0.1:5000> SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster
1) "172.20.0.2"
2) "6379"
```

Answer (score 0):

follow your `Docker commands` and `sentinel.conf`, it works to me.

```
1:S 23 Dec 2020 03:14:59.370 * Connecting to MASTER redis-0:6379
1:S 23 Dec 2020 03:14:59.371 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 23 Dec 2020 03:14:59.371 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 23 Dec 2020 03:14:59.371 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 23 Dec 2020 03:14:59.372 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request 5c52aa10610b365f29fec2968e095c5b49eb6136:43).
1:S 23 Dec 2020 03:14:59.373 * Full resync from master: 1f843162cf808a500a5d57392baf585f6e1679a3:0
```

Maybe you can check redis-0 logs，does it accept replica' ask.

Comment: no, it's one of replica. those logs show that replica sync success from master.

Comment: Are those Logs with Sentinel Up and Connectet to the Redis M-S? Because without Sentinel, also for me works fine as i described in my post.